# Replacing a particular element in column y with reference to particular element in column x

Tags: python, pandas

I am working on car sales data on python using pandas:
***Car***  Mercedes,Audi,BMW,Volkswagon,Mercedes,BMW

***Type*** Sedan,Crossover, *Other*,Van,*Other*,SUV

Now I want to replace 'Other' in type as: when car= Mercedes then type=Sedan and when car= BMW then type=SUV and so on using for loop.
I am struggling to get this done. Require assistance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Edit: updated answer based on example data you provided

#### Setup - notice I added rows which have "Other" in the `body` column:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

cars = [['Ford',15500.0,'crossover',68,2.5,'Gas','yes',2010,'Kuga','full'],
        ['Mercedes-Benz',20500.0,'sedan',173,1.8,'Gas','yes',2011,'E-Class','rear'],
        ['Mercedes-Benz',20500.0,"Other",173,1.8,'Gas','yes',2011,'E-Class','rear'],
        ['Ford',15500.0,"Other",68,2.5,'Gas','yes',2010,'Kuga','full']] 

car_sales = pd.DataFrame(cars, columns=['car','price','body','mileage','engV','engType','registration','year','model','drive'])
```

#### Step 1 - replace the "Other" values with NaN  (this allows you to use the fillna function):

```
car_sales["body"].replace("Other", np.nan, inplace=True)
```

#### Step 2 - create the dictionary map of values for each car type, and then use fillna to fill in the values:

```
car_types = {"Mercedes-Benz":"sedan", "Ford":"crossover"}
car_sales["body"].fillna(car_sales["car"].map(car_types), inplace=True)
```

Comment: Hi there, it is giving out error as                                                                  ValueError: shape mismatch: value array of shape (8213,) could not be broadcast to indexing result of shape (677,)

Comment: Can you post a minimal example of your DataFrame to copy?

Comment: Hi sorry for this late reply. was not well.   
         
cars = [['Ford',15500.0,'crossover',68,2.5,'Gas','yes',2010,'Kuga','full'],['Mercedes-Benz',20500.0,'sedan',173,1.8,'Gas','yes',2011,'E-Class','rear']]

car_sales = pd.Dataframe(cars, columns=['car','price','body','mileage','engV','engType','registration','year','model','drive'])

Comment: Ok see my updated answer based on the data you provided. I assume you're trying to replace "Other" values in the `body` column, although there aren't any rows like this in the example you provided.

Comment: Yes. You guessed it right. Thank you very much. I will try this and come back. Thnaks

Answer (score 1):

Create a dictionary with car as key and type as value,

```
d = {'Mercedes' : 'Sedan', 'BMW' : 'SUV'}
```

Now use map to map the column to values,

```
df.loc[df['Type'] == 'Other', 'Car'].map(d)
```

Provide a sample of your dataframe for a more complete answer